How to run shimmer effect every time a widget becomes visible?
I have a button widget and I want to run a shimmer effect, e.g. using the shimmer and visibility_detector packages (I am not set on these). The idea is that the button gets a little eye-catcher every time it becomes visible. I use a simple stateful widget and a Future.delayed function. My implementation runs my _startShimmer every time the widget becomes visible. But it does not shimmer.
Has anyone done something similar? I suspect that the shimmer package has its own state and when you set loop to 1 it does not reactivate, even if enabled is set to true. I also tried setting loop to 0 (which means it loops infinitely), but that didn't help.
class CTAWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const CTAWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  CTAWidgetState createState() => CTAWidgetState();
}

class CTAWidgetState extends State<CTAWidget>
    with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  bool _shimmer = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _startShimmer();
  }

  void _startShimmer() {
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          _shimmer = true;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return VisibilityDetector(
      key: const Key('cta_widget'),
      onVisibilityChanged: (VisibilityInfo info) {
        // Start shimmer effect when the widget is fully visible
        if (info.visibleFraction == 1) {
          _startShimmer();
        }
      },
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          // Shimmer effect
          Shimmer.fromColors(
            baseColor: AppColors.yellow500,
            highlightColor: AppColors.yellow100,
            enabled: _shimmer,
            loop: 1,
            child: Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 56,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
              decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                color: AppColors.yellow500,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          // Button content
          Container(
            // My actual button
          ),
        ],
      ),
    )
  }
}


Maybe something like this? https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_animate
